# Frozen training of Keras / Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, azure-machine-learning-service

I am training CNN Keras/TF models in AzureML on GPU compute instance.
Below exemplary architecture that I am running:

```
def define_model_1D_v17():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add( Conv1D(256, (5,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(22, 20)))
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform',))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
   model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy ', metrics=['accuracy'])
   return model
```

I observe "non deterministic" problem of "freezing" training procedure.
More specifically, some invocations of:

```
history = model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, validation_data=test_gen, verbose=1)
```

have almost constant loss/accuracy over batches and epochs (only slightly oscillating).
Exemplary printout is following (first run frozen, second ok):

```
fold 2 a45db86ea43b5a95a96ef7be349d9f2f
Epoch 1/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 50s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5489 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 2/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 3/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 4/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 5/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 6/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 7/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 8/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 9/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
Epoch 10/10
1846/1846 [==============================] - 49s 27ms/step - loss: 0.4508 - accuracy: 0.5492 - val_loss: 0.5220 - val_accuracy: 0.47
14716/14716 [==============================] - 26s 2ms/step
fold 3 8fa8e37b3c345f05b5aeff167939cc96
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1372 - accuracy: 0.8224 - val_loss: 0.0954 - val_accuracy: 0.86
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 50s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1058 - accuracy: 0.8511 - val_loss: 0.0921 - val_accuracy: 0.87
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1038 - accuracy: 0.8539 - val_loss: 0.0944 - val_accuracy: 0.86
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1021 - accuracy: 0.8563 - val_loss: 0.0931 - val_accuracy: 0.86
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1003 - accuracy: 0.8590 - val_loss: 0.0912 - val_accuracy: 0.87
Epoch 6/10
 1875/1875 [==============================] - 50s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0982 - accuracy: 0.8623 - val_loss: 0.0915 - val_accuracy: 0.87
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0957 - accuracy: 0.8665 - val_loss: 0.0918 - val_accuracy: 0.87
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0924 - accuracy: 0.8723 - val_loss: 0.0928 - val_accuracy: 0.86
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0882 - accuracy: 0.8795 - val_loss: 0.0943 - val_accuracy: 0.86
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0835 - accuracy: 0.8874 - val_loss: 0.0950 - val_accuracy: 0.86
```

I tried both "he_uniform" and default kernel initializer, no effect.

I also monitor RAM usage and is not close to full.

I also checked the predictions that those are actually screwed up, not only the printout.

Interestingly, I also experienced this type of problems in the past on CPU machine (with older version of Keras/TF).

How to fix/limit this problem?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of your input data? Loss not improving means the model isn't learning. That could be caused by not being able to generalize, or maybe getting stuck in local minima. Try reducing learning rate by 90% if you feel your dataset is large and heterogeneous enough. Try a learning rate of 0.00005 or 0.00001. The kernel initializer would cause a bit more predictable issues. If it were a memory issue, you'd get an error about memory and training would stop.

Comment: Using `mean_squared_error` with `accuracy` does not make sense, one is a regression loss and other one is a classification metric. Your model is configured for classification therefore you need to use `binary_crossentropy` if your intention is doing binary classification. Think how BCE penalizes wrong predictions compared to MSE.

Comment: @Frightera Correct, fixed. I will check if this helps.

Comment: @Frightera Yes it was the reason. Good catch and thank you!